# How to test equality of MongoDB filters (BSON) in Java/Groovy?

Tags: java, mongodb, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I'm generating MongoDB-queries unsing the [Filters-API](http://api.mongodb.org/java/3.0/?com/mongodb/client/model/Filters.html).

```
Bson r1 = Filters.and(Filters.eq("a","b"), Filters.eq("c","d"))
Bson r2 = Filters.and(Filters.eq("a","b"), Filters.eq("c","d"))
```

But how can I check the result for equality? For example:

```
r1.equals(r2)
```

and

```
r1.dump().equals(r2.dump())
```

don't work.

Comment: Just to be clear, you are asking for something like "unit tests" how to see if one definition is the same as another? Did you look at the driver tests in any language? That should give you a pretty good indication of how this is done for their own unit tests. Also kind of wondering why you would bother, since this is exactly the sort of "unit testing" that is really the domain of the "driver" and not really for your application.

Comment: @BlakesSeven The method I'd like to test uses the Filter API to generate (more or less complex) filter queries. I'd like to test if the method generates the correct output according to the parameters it takes.

Comment: Understood. But the big basic hint there was *"look at how the drivers do it"* since that code is readilly accessible. Every single language driver does it in the same way, by basically having an expected data structure, then using the methods to dump the "standard form" of that data structure from the constructed query to see if they are are the same. Java/Groovy does not have "native" data structure notation. But you do have BSON Document objects to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing you could do is:

- convert Bson to BsonDocument
- compare the JSON Strings

Here is what I found on
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/mongodb-user/peeL8wIWxwA/ZHpYglQEDQAJ

```
BsonDocument b1 = r1.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY);
BsonDocument b2 = r2.toBsonDocument(BsonDocument.class, MongoClient.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY);
```